# AD Management tool

Tags: powershell

Trying to build a custom Active directory management tool but running into some issues when wrapping it up into a menu.

```
do
 {
    Show-Menu
    $selection = Read-Host "Make your selection"
    switch ($selection)
    {
    '1' { #===Add Admin===
    Clear-Host
        $Workstation = Read-Host "Workstation\IP Address"
        $EndUser = Read-Host "EndUser"
        $AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Workstation/Administrators,group"
        $User = [ADSI]"WinNT://USA/$EndUser,user"
        $AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)
    } '2' { #===Remove Admin===
    Clear-Host
        $Workstation = Read-Host "Workstation\IP Address"
        $EndUser = Read-Host "ACEID"
        $AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Workstation/Administrators,group"
        $User = [ADSI]"WinNT://USA/$EndUser,user"
        $AdminGroup.remove($User.Path)
    } '3' { #===ADUC===
    Clear-Host
        runas /netonly /user:USA\ADM$env:USERNAME "mmc C:\Windows\System32\dsa.msc"
    } '4' { #===Computer Management===
    Clear-Host
        runas /netonly /user:USA\ADM$env:USERNAME "mmc C:\Windows\System32\compmgmt.msc"
    } '5' {
    Clear-Host
        $EndUser = Read-Host "Username?"
        (Get-ADUser $EndUser -Properties MemberOf).memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object name | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Shr*"}
        pause
    }
    }
 
 }
 until ($selection -eq 'q')
```

options 1-4 work as intended, however option 5 does not output anything.  When I copy the code for 5 and do it separately in another PowerShell instance it outputs the result that I want, but the above does not work despite the others working flawlessly.  Am I missing something?  I have literally copy and pasted the code back and forth and in one instance it works, but as soon as I run the script as a whole or through ISE it does not give me any output.

Specifically looking at

```
(Get-ADUser $EndUser -Properties MemberOf).memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object name | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Shr*"}
```

When it is wrapped in the menu it does not work, but if I run it in powershell and put in a username for the $EndUser variable it gives me the expected results.

Comment: add ```write-host``` in front of (get-aduser...

Comment: How do I wrap the entire ```(Get-ADUser $EndUser -Properties MemberOf).memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object name | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Shr*"}``` in write host?  If I just add Write-Host in front of it I only get the results of the ```(Get-ADUser $EndUser -Properties MemberOf).memberof.```

Comment: @Toni Thank you for the recommendation.  When I added Write-Host with Parentheses around the problem code it output the information I wanted but not in a useful way.  I found adding a pipe to Format-Table gave me exactly what I was looking for.

```(Get-ADUser $EndUser -Properties MemberOf).memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object name | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Shr*"} | Format-Table```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to just add Write-Host to the beginning as recommended but it only output the first string of code.  I then added parenthesis around the code so the Write-Host would target all of it, but that did not output what I wanted either.

```
Write-Host ((Get-ADUser $EndUser -Properties MemberOf).memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object name | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Shr*"})
```

This output the information but was in the format:

***@{name=shr_Share1} @{name=shr_Share2} @{name=shr_Share3}***

Progress, but not quite right.  I want to be able to easily copy and paste the information from the output.

Adding a | Format-Table to the end of the string gave me what I wanted:

```
(Get-ADUser $EndUser -Properties MemberOf).memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object name | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Shr*"} | Format-Table
```

***name***
***----***
***shr_Share1***
***shr_Share2***
***shr_Share3***